# How do I exit a for loop in python 2.7 without raising Exceptions

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, exception

I have a for loop that iterates across a list of floats.  My original intention was that I could do a for loop with an if statement to 'do stuff' if my  data is > than x percentage…however I've come to realize that this method causes duplication of data presented.  It IS factually right, but it is not what I desired nor intended.  So, my mock data has something that is way larger than reality and it triggers the if condition on all lower percentages.  I really just want it to trigger on the largest percentage and not onto the smaller conditions below…how would I do that in the most pythonic way possible?

This is the sample code solution I threw together but I think having to involve raising exceptions using a try/catch block is probably not as clean as other solutions.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

percentages =  [0.2,0.5, 0.75, 1, 2, 5]
resultingPercentage = 9


for i in sorted(percentages, reverse=True):
    try:
        if resultingPercentage > i:
            print "We found an opportunity greater than %.2f%% points" %i
            raise Exception
    except:
        #continue
        break
```

Comment: try that example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_break_statement.htm … also from try a break will call finally ; the raise is not necessary at all as you can see in the example linked.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to do, your sample code exits immediately, so hard to tell what you are trying to demonstrate. E.g. You could just `break` immediately instead of `raise -> except -> break`. You may also want to look at `itertools` module as there are lots of support for iterator algebra, in particular `itertools.takewhile()` might help.

Comment: alright, those suggestions did it.  I didn't realize I could just use the `break` statement within my if statement in the loop which was why I did it a an exception, I'll mark either of these as the solved answer if given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as nobody else has posted it as an answer yet and to mark this question as answered, you can break out of a loop without the `break` statement appearing in an exception handler:

```
percentages =  [0.2,0.5, 0.75, 1, 2, 5]
resultingPercentage = 9

for i in sorted(percentages, reverse=True):
    if resultingPercentage > i:
        print "We found an opportunity greater than %.2f%% points" %i
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `max` function to get the largest percentage from the list, then just do a single `if` statement with only that percentage:

```
percentages =  [0.2,0.5, 0.75, 1, 2, 5]
resultingPercentage = 9
maxPercentage = max(percentages)
if resultingPercentage > maxPercentage:
    print "We found an opportunity greater than %.2f%% points" %maxPercentage
```

Comment: there is MUCH more going on that isn't being shown here - the resultingPercentage variable is in itself generated into a for loop and that sample snippet was what I intended to write after generating the resultingPercentage...it changes constantly so, picking the max value won't work.  I just put a high number in there to demonstrate that the code would run for each value, including ones lower - in reality my resultingPercentage value will be a middle value and almost NEVER be equal to or greater than max.  I didn't want to leave you hanging, thank you for your help